# Affine Algebraic Sets - Equivalence Statement

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I am just learning about affine algebraic sets and am struggling with the following problem.

> Consider the algebraic sets; $A=\lbrace (x,y) \mid y=x^2\rbrace$
>   (parabola) and $B=\lbrace (x,y) \mid y=0\rbrace$ (the $x$-axis). Show
>   that  $$\mathcal{I}(A\cap B)=\mbox{rad}(\mathcal{I}(A) +
>  \mathcal{I}(B))$$ Comment: This formula is in fact true in general,
>   for any two algebraic sets.

**Basic definitions:**

Let $k$ be a field. Let $S$ be a subset of functions in the coordinate ring $k[\mathbb{A}^n]$. Let $A$ be any subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$. Then

- $\mathcal{Z}(S)=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\in\mathbb{A}^n|f(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=0 \hspace{3mm}\forall f\in S\}$
- $\mathcal{I}(A)=\{f\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n|f(a_1,\cdots,a_n)=0\hspace{3mm}\forall(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in A\}$
- rad$(I)=\{a\in R|a^k\in I\text{ for some }k\geq 1\}$

**Some Known Properties:**

- $S\subseteq \mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(S))$
- $\mathcal{I}(A\cup B)=\mathcal{I}(A)\cap\mathcal{I}(B)$
- $A\subseteq B\Rightarrow \mathcal{I}(B)\subseteq\mathcal{I}(A)$
- $\mathcal{Z}(I)\cup\mathcal{Z}(J)=\mathcal{Z}(IJ)$

Note: I have more properties, but I thought these were some that could be helpful for this problem.

---

**My Attempt**:

Assume the hypothesis. By definition, $A=\mathcal{Z}(y-x^2)$ and $B=\mathcal{Z}(y)$. First we will determine $\mathcal{I}(A\cap B)$. Notice
\begin{eqnarray*}
A\cap B &=& \lbrace (x,y) \mid y=x^2\rbrace \cap \lbrace (x,y) \mid y=0\rbrace\\
&=& \{(x,y)|y=x^2\text{ and }y=0\}\\
&=&\{(x,0)|x^2=0 \}\\
&=&\{(0,0)\}
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore by the example shown in class (I can explain the reasoning if not obvious), we know
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{I}(A\cap B) &=& \mathcal{I}(\{(0,0)\})\\
&=& \langle x-0,y-0\rangle\\
&=& \langle x,y\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}

Notice $\mathcal{I}(A)=\langle y-x^2\rangle $ and $\mathcal{I}(B)=\langle y\rangle$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{I}(A)+\mathcal{I}(B)&=&\langle y-x^2,y\rangle\\
&=&\{f_1(y-x^2)+f_2y|f_i\in k[x,y]\}\\
&=& \{f_1y-f_1x^2+f_2y|f_i\in k[x,y]\}\\
&=& \{-f_1(x^2)+(f_1+f_2)y|f_i\in k[x,y]\}\\
&=& \langle x^2, y\rangle
\end{eqnarray*} 
Recall $k[x,y]/\langle x,y\rangle\cong k$. Because $k$ is a field, we know $k[x,y]/\langle x,y\rangle$ is a field. Therefore $\langle x,y\rangle$ is maximal. Notice
$$
\langle x,y\rangle ^2\subseteq \langle x^2,y\rangle \subseteq \langle x,y\rangle
$$
Then by proposition, we know rad$(\langle x^2,y\rangle)=\langle x,y\rangle$.

Hence $\mathcal{I}(A\cap B)=\mbox{rad}(\mathcal{I}(A) +
 \mathcal{I}(B))$.

---

Am I on the right track here? I keep second guessing myself. Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: @k.stm Thank you for the confirmation. I am trying to find the radical ideal at the moment, and I getting slightly confused here. I added more to my question above. But I don't see what comes next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $I(A)+I(B)=(y-x^2,y)=(x^2,y)$, then $rad (I(A)+I(B))=(x,y)$, therefore $I(A \cap B)=rad({I(A)+I(B)}) $

Answer (score 1):

So you only need to show that $\operatorname{rad} (y-x^2, y) = (x, y)$.

*Hint*: Show that $\operatorname{rad} I$ is an ideal for all ideals $I$ in any ring $R$. (Maybe you already know that?) Then it suffices to show that:

- $(x, y)$ is a maximal ideal in $k[\mathbb A^2] = k[x,y]$,
- $(y - x^2, y)$ is not all of $k[x,y]$, … so
- $\operatorname{rad} (y - x^2, y)$ is not all of $k[x,y]$, and
- $x, y ∈ \operatorname{rad} (y-x^2, y)$.

Why does it suffice?

Comment: I do know that $I\subseteq \text{rad}(I)$ in a proposition, so I do have that first part. I will try using your hint and continue to revise my question. I will let you know when posted. Thank you for the hint. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I revised my answer and ended up going with Mustafa's approach. I did some reading on your approach, and I believe your hint is using concepts we have not yet covered in my class. The concept I think you wanted me to apply the following proposition: If $M=(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal and $Q=(y-x^2,y)$ is an ideal with $(x,y)^2\subseteq (y-x^2,y)\subseteq M$, then rad$((y-x^2,y))=M$. We just never covered this in class. Still a great hint though.

Comment: @jm.byrnes Actually, I just wanted to give you hints on how to justify the essential identity $\operatorname{rad} (x^2, y) = (x, y)$, which was basically the remaining thing you needed to show and is used in Mustafas answer, too. Mustafa and I have the same approach.